# Docker container - MYSQL_RANDOM_ROOT_PASSWORD not showing output in STDOUT

Tags: mysql, docker, dockerfile

I am new to docker so this can be a noob question.

I would like to print out the root password for MySQL in stdout, to do it I did set:

ENV MYSQL_RANDOM_ROOT_PASSWORD yes

Based on the manual https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/docker-mysql-more-topics.html#docker_var_mysql_random_root_password - The password is printed to stdout of the container and can be found by looking at the container’s log but I don't see it.

Here's link to my container: https://hub.docker.com/r/thk1/lamp

I also have second problem. When I run the container on Synology NAS server I can see the stdout log by using DSM application. But when I run the container on my Windows by doing docker build and docker run, and then viewing docker logs I can't see anything (yes the container is running when I check the logs).

So my questions are - what am I doing wrong in case of the MYSQL_RANDOM_ROOT_PASSWORD and why I can't view logs?

If someone is offended by my questions because /put here whatever reason you want/ then remember that everyone learns and rather instead of biting, help me to be a better man. :)

Comment: Please ask one question at a time. These two questions are unrelated, so should be posted separately.

Comment: @SiHa The second question is lesser importance for me, but thank You for pointing that out.

Comment: you are not importing your image from mysql how should the ENV `MYSQL_RANDOM_ROOT_PASSWORD` works ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest to add this to your "run-lamp.sh":

```
PASS=`head /dev/urandom | tr -dc A-Za-z0-9 | head -c 13 ; echo ''`
mysqladmin -u root password $PASS
echo "Root Password is $PASS"
```

in this way you setup and print the password to docker logs.

**PS**: the ENV you use will only works on mysql official image.

Comment: the random password generator is taken from : https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/230673/how-to-generate-a-random-string

Comment: Thank You, that was it. The ENV MYSQL_RANDOM_ROOT_PASSWORD didn't work. I thought that this is universal variable for docker.